# Regex to remove blank lines at the end of a CSV

Tags: regex

I have the following CSV data:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
```

And I'm using the the following regex pattern to remove blank lines at the end of the CSV: `[,\s]+$`

The issue is that this captures the empty columns in the fourth line too (`1,2,3,4,5,,,,`). How can I avoid this?

After removing the match, the desired output should be the following:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,,,,,
```

Comment: Can you post what your desired output would be?

Comment: @AaronMeese sorry about that. Just did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to look for only empty lines at the end of the file and remove them all:

```
(\n,*)+$/g
```

An example can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/YOk2nb/3), it just requires using an empty substitution as demonstrated.

Comment: thanks! isn't this still capturing the last 3 lines though?

Comment: OH by blank you mean filled with commas, not empty lines. Completely misunderstood the question! Just a minute.

Comment: my bad! I wasn't clear in my initial post